# Assign a value to an object variable when the object variable name is in another variable

Tags: c#

I have a class like so:

```
Class A
{
     int a;
     string b;
     .....
     .....
     ......//up to 200
}
```

And I need to set the value of a or b from a variable, say:

```
var varValue;
```

So, the variable `varValue` is accompanied by another variable:

```
string varName='a';
```

So, I need to create an object and assign the value such that if `varName` is 'a', the corresponding `varValue` is assigned to `int a;` and vice versa if `varName` is 'b'

I need this because I have a service which returns just the property name and its corresponding value as a tuple and I need to put this in a model, but the tuple may come in any order and I need to assign the value to the object properly.

And I dont want to use if-else since I have around 200 variables in my class.

Comment: There's no good reason to need to do this - elaborate on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can't you have the condition like
`if (varName = 'a')
{
    ObjA.a = varValue;
}
else
{
ObjA.b = varValue;
}`

Comment: you can use getName() function. And use If-Else structure to assign value.

Comment: @AntP : Done, and everyone else, my class in 200 variable strong, so, prefer not to use if-else if possible.

Comment: How **int a** ever would be == 'a'?

Comment: You can use reflection to set fields values (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h.aspx)).

Comment: So, hang on, you expect to be able to conditionally assign `int a` or `string b` (*different types*) from a statically-typed variable `var varValue`? Before we even get to `varName`, that is simply not possible. By the way, sounds like you just need a dictionary other key/value pair mechanism, not to be reflecting variable names.

Comment: 200 variables in a single class... wouldn't it be better to use a lookup table instead? But if you have to go down this route, then look into reflection. Be sure to add type and error checking... (field not existing, unable to convert value to field type, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different ways to achieve something like that, but they all have their drawbacks. As commenters mentioned. Having 200 different named variables is bad design, and even without knowing the exact requirements of your software, it can almost certainly be written better.

1. Use a dictionary

Rather than storing your data as separate variables, use a Dictionary as a data container, keyed to a name:

```
Dictionary<string, object> myVariables = new Dictionary<string,object();
myVariables.Add("a", "value for a");
myVariables.Add("b", "value for b"); 
//etc.
```

Now you can use:

```
Tuple<string, object> myResult = new Tuple(varName, myVariables[varName]);
```

This loses type safety, but it seems from your example that you're already returning any number of different types (int, string) as part of a generic "varValue" instance. Also, don't forget to add error checking - either use `myVariables.TryGetValue` to get the value safely, or check `myVariables.ContainsKey` before accessing.

2. Reflection

Using reflection, you can retrieve the value of a variable whose name is only known at runtime:

```
object varValue = this.GetType()
.GetField(varName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
.GetValue(this);
```

and now you can return the tuple based on the varName and varValue again. Again, like the Dictionary approach, you have to be careful and make sure you validate that the requested varName exists and has a value before returning it.

Also, returning a value by reflection using nothing but its name is a potential security risk, allowing any caller to request any private value. Of course, if the caller calls your code directly, it can *already* access your values via reflection. But if this is exposed as part of a remote service, it could (theoretically) allow access to unexpected data.

3. Redesign

But really, both of these approaches are just band-aids around a bad design. If you can refactor your class so that the data isn't stored so haphazardly, it's best to do so. But without knowing the use case, it's hard to recommend anything specific.